# Angular changing ng-class on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change a class that I am creating based on a value that I get from json, and then change it if user cliks on it, but I am not getting that to work.

This is my code in the controller:

```
$scope.like = function(){
      if ($scope.class === "ion-ios-heart-outline")
        $scope.class = "ion-heart";
      else
        $scope.class = "ion-ios-heart-outline";
    };
```

And the element in the view:

```
<i ng-click="like()" ng-class="{ 'ion-heart' : article.like == 1, 'ion-ios-heart-outline' : article.like == 0}">
```

Comment: If you are checking `article.like == 1` on view, why not just change value of same flag in controller? Also, you are not using `$scope.class` anywhere in view.

Comment: could you please show the code example of how to do that?

Comment: Pass the article to the like function `ng-click="like(article)"` and set the like flag to 1 `$scope.like = function(article){article.like : article.like == 1 ? 0 : 1; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `$scope.class` (which is never used in the view) and `ng-class`, so I am not entirely sure what you want to do. But I guess what you are looking for is this:

```
$scope.article.like = 0;
$scope.like = function() {
    $scope.article.like = $scope.article.like == 0 ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Then the CSS classes will be changed based on whether the article was liked or not.

Comment: Don't forget to add `article` to the parameters of the function. On second thought, unless it's not inside `ngRepeat` - you don't need to

Comment: @AlonEitan That depends entirely on the use case.

Comment: You can also check for `!$scope.article.like`. If OP is directly using this variable on view, first click will not be handled. Try `!$scope.article.like?1:0` This will handle `undefined` and `0`

Comment: @str Agreed. There is not enough content in the question to decide how it should be done - But your answer is good

Comment: @Rajesh True. But I assumed `article.like` to be defined before that, otherwise applying the `ion-ios-heart-outline` class would not work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

check out this plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1LNxXlDRpzzZImspJJKE?p=preview

```
$scope.article= {}; 
$scope.article.like = 1;
$scope.like = function()
{
 $scope.article.like = ($scope.article.like === 0 ? 1 : 0);
};
```

hopefully you are trying to set the class based on the value on article.like in the